# Paypal ipn anything wrong with this section

Tags: php, sql, paypal

I got my Paypal ipn to work. But I changed some things and now I can not remember what I changed. I used a series of INSERTS to monitor where the process of the ipn fails. It looks like it does not pass this part of my ipn. Here is the code:

```
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

Why is my Paypal ipn not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also struggled a lot with paypal ipn last week,below is my working code you can refer

```
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 


    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         
      $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
      $req  .= "&$key=$value";              
    }


    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        fputs($fp, "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($req)."\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, $req. "\r\n\r\n"); 

        $ipn_response = '';

    while (!feof($fp)) {                     
      $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);              
    }
    fclose($fp);

   if ( eregi("VERIFIED",$ipn_response) ) {}
```